# Securing wire to board connectors with glue

Tags: identification, connector, crimp, glue

I'm trying to secure wire to board connectors and crimps with glue to withstand vibrations and shocks. I came across the following cases in commercially available devices. Please help me identify these glues/ fillers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first shows hot-melt. The second is something like nail polish.  Hot melt is fairly common for tacking down components etc so they don’t vibrate.

Comment: By hot melt do you mean glue sticks (hot glue)? I have never been able to apply them with a glue gun like that. The glue in the picture is harder and has flown even inside the connector holes. It also doesn't come off like hot glue. Is it a special type?

Comment: Your glue gun was probably not hot enough. There are a variety of glue sticks other than the cheapy stuff you get from craft shops. The likes of Bostik have a selection.